# What inequalities involve sums of products of the form $\sum_{(i_1, \ldots , i_N) \in S_N ^{(n)}} \prod_{j=1} ^ N i_j \quad?$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, inequality

What is the better inequality (below and above) for the next expression:

$$\sum_{(i_1, \ldots , i_N) \in S_N ^{(n)}} \prod_{j=1} ^ N i_j \quad?$$

where $S_N ^{(n)}$ is the set of permutations of $N$ elements take from $n.$

I try using the first and last $N$ terms of $[n]$ respectively, but it is not enough because I lose a lot. And I don't know if the AM–GM inequality
work due to the equality between AM–GM $(\text{when}\quad i_1=i_2=i_=\ldots)$ knowing that in this case it's not possible for being permutation.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Sorry for my English, I'm not native. :v

Comment: Hey, just to say that such things have a name, after some multiplying. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial Rather a lot is known so could be of some use. Depends on what you want.

Comment: What do you mean "permutation of $N$ elements taken from $n$"? Do you mean you have $n$ numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and you form an $N$-tuple $(x_{k_1}, x_{k_2} \ldots x_{k_N})$ from them where $1 \le k_1, \ldots, k_N \le n$ and the $k_i$ are distinct. Do the order of $k_i$ matter? i.e. when $N = 3$ and $n \ge 10$, the $3$-tuple $(x_1,x_2,x_{10})$ is consider to be the same as $(x_{10},x_2,x_1)$.

Comment: Yeah! Your interpretation is righ, but the order matter. $(x_1,x_2,x_{10}) \not= (x_{10},x_2,x_1)$

Comment: Other form of write the sum is $N! \sum_{(i_1< \ldots < i_N) \in S_N ^{(n)}} \prod_{j=1} ^ N i_j $

Comment: In that case $\sigma_N = \frac{S_N^{(n)}}{N!}$ will be the N-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) associated with $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Let $s_N = \frac{\sigma_N}{\binom{n}{N}}$. When all $x_i$ are real, you have the [Newton inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_inequalities): $s_{k-1}s_{k+1} \le s_k^2$. When all $x_i$ are positive, you have [Maclaurin's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin's_inequality): $s_1 \ge \sqrt{s_2} \le \sqrt[3]{s_3} \ge \cdots \ge \sqrt[n]{s_n}$.

Comment: BTW, what is your $\{ x_1,\ldots, x_n \}$. Is that $[n] = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$ or something more general?

Comment: I'm going to look to see if I can get what I want with the Maclaurin's inequalities. $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ Thanks :)